# Unable to type after click with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I've tried almost anything but still unable to insert username after clicking input.
I know there is other solutions to do so without clicking I also tried but still not working...

- [How to fill an input field using Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966510/how-to-fill-an-input-field-using-puppeteer/56772379)
- [Unable to login with Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202761/unable-to-login-with-puppeteer)

**Click** is working and cursor **blinking** now all I need is just to 'type' something.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const creds = {
    email: "myemail",
    password: "mypassword",
};

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--start-maximized']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    //set viewport
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
    })
    await page.goto('https://qa.traffilog.co.il/new_web/index.htm', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    const username = await page.$x('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/input[1]');

    await username[0].click();
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    await page.type(username, creds.email);
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });


    // await browser.close();
})

();
```

Comment: You can use type without specifying a target. You can also use page.keyboard.press()

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read in the docs Page.type takes a selector not an ElementHandle. But because you are using an ElementHandle you could try to set the input value by using `username[0].value=creds.email`